# Extend jquery with allow only numbers

Tags: jquery

What i want to do is set up a extended jquery function that allow no numbers in textboxes. This is what I have:

```
$.fn.onlyNumbers = function(evt) {
    var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Is this correct?
How do i call it when it is an extended function and get it to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you understood how a jQuery plugin works.

Your function is called with `this` being the jQuery object the function was called on. Inside this function you need to register a `keypress` event to handle those characters - oh, and you don't need any browser-specific code as jQuery does that part for you.

Try this:

```
$.fn.onlyNumbers = function() {
    return this.keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which > 31 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if someone pastes the numbers in? It's more bulletproof to check the value of the textbox on keyup, and replace it with a numeric version of that value (regex, anyone?).

Comment: Sounds more like a comment to me.